# Error while deleting a file from amazon s3 bucket

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete a file from s3 bucket using AWS SDK android.
I have followed the tutorial below to set up my bucket.
https://grokonez.com/android/uploaddownload-files-images-amazon-s3-android.

The uploading and downloading work fine. But when I try to delete a file, my application crashes.

Here is the code I am using

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(KEY, SECRET);
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
s3Client.deleteObject(bucketName, folderPath);
```

Comment: Does the IAM role have access to remove from the bucket?

Comment: Can you post the crash message and the stack trace? Are you invoking deleteObject from main thread or a background thread? What version of SDK and Android are you using?

Comment: Here is the logcat
https://pastebin.com/7MCbvQ3j

Answer (score 1):

You should call delete object method in background thread.

`new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    s3client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(AWS_BUCKET, "Path"));
                }
            }).start();`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this crash because Android does not let you make a network call from a main thread. You need to wrap this call from a background thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() 
           BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(KEY, SECRET);
           AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
           s3Client.deleteObject(bucketName, folderPath);
   }
}).start();
```